# Show input elements hidden under keyboard Android PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, automated-tests, iscroll

I have a form in which one input element gets hidden under keyboard after focusing on it. I don't want my page to get resized.

Can this be handled using scroll, so that only the form div gets scrolled to that particular element?

Or any other approach to this?

I'm not using `jquery-mobile` and I have tried `scrollToElement` of `iScroll 5`, but to no use.

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="header">
        <img alt="" class="header_logo" src="" />

    </div>
    <div id="main">


        <div id="map-canvas"><input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Area" /></div> 
        <form id="booking_form" action="#" >

            <input type="tel" id="contact_no" placeholder="Contact Number*" maxlength="10"/>
            <div class="group">
                <span id="get_pick_location" class="gps_icon" title="Press to get current location address/ Select a point on map to get address"></span><textarea cols="10" id="pick_up_location" placeholder="Pickup Location*" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <span id="get_drop_location" class="gps_icon" title="Press to get current location address/ Select a point on map to get address"></span><textarea cols="10" id="drop_off_location" placeholder="Drop off Location*" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="pick_up_time" placeholder="Pickup time*" />
            <input type="text" id="car_model" placeholder="Car*" /> 
            <input type="submit" id="confirm_booking" class="custom_button" value="Confirm Booking" />
        </form>     
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <button id="create_booking" class="custom_button">Book Now</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

The input field car_model gets hidden under keyboard. I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my manifest file.

```
theScroll = new IScroll('form');
$('#car_model').focus(function(){
    theScroll.scrollTo($('#car_model'));
});
```

Comment: Write some code so we can see whats the problem. Imagining your code is quite difficult.

Comment: Please suggest an approach

Comment: You should only be using 1 method to show the input.  Either `adjustPan` or `scrollTo` - not both.

Comment: When I don't add adjustPan, showing keyboard resizes the web page.

Comment: Sounds like you also have `adjustResize` enabled.

Comment: No, I only have adjustPan enabled. Default value for windowSoftInputMode is adjustUnspecified, I think.

Comment: When I had similar issue, I solved it by disabling full screen in config.xml. (but then my app is resized when the keyboard opens, which seems not to be what you want)

Comment: No, I don't want the screen to be resized

Comment: try this code when input is focused `var position = $(this).offset().top; $.mobile.silentScroll(position);`

Comment: "scrollTo" accept the parameters as "x, y, timeStamp". But if you want to pass the DOM then you have to use "scrollToElement" which accept parameters "CSS_SELECTOR, timeStamp". Therefore it should be "theScroll.scrollToElement('#car_model',0)"